# Matplotlib, plot a vector of numbers as a rectangle filled with numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib

So let's say I have a vector of numbers.

```py
np.random.randn(5).round(2).tolist()

[2.05, -1.57, 1.07, 1.37, 0.32]
```

I want a draw a rectangle that shows this elements as numbers in a rectangle.
Something like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this in matplotlib?

Answer (score 2):

A bit convoluted but you could take advantage of `seaborn.heatmap`, creating a white colormap:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

data = np.random.randn(5).round(2).tolist()

linewidth = 2

ax = sns.heatmap([data], annot=True, cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['w', 'w'], N=1),
            linewidths=linewidth, linecolor='black', square=True,
            cbar=False, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

In this case, the external lines won't be as thick as the internal ones. If needed, this can be fixed with:

```
ax.axhline(y=0, color='black', lw=linewidth*2)
ax.axhline(y=1, color='black', lw=linewidth*2)
ax.axvline(x=0, color='black', lw=linewidth*2)
ax.axvline(x=len(data), color='black', lw=linewidth*2)
```

Edit: avoid these lines and add `clip_on=False` to `sns.heatmap` (thanks/credit @JohanC)

Output:

[image]

Comment: To have all lines the same thickness: `sns.heatmap(...., clip_on=False)` ....

Answer (score 1):

We can add rectangles , and annotate them in a for loop.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Our numbers
nums = np.random.randn(5).round(2).tolist()

# rectangle_size
rectangle_size = 2

# We want rectangles look squared, you can change if you want
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [rectangle_size * len(nums), rectangle_size]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(len(nums)):
    # We are adding rectangles
    # You can change colors as you wish
    plt.broken_barh([(rectangle_size * i, rectangle_size)], (0, rectangle_size), facecolors='white', edgecolor='black'
                    ,linewidth = 1)

    # We are calculating where to annotate numbers
    cy = rectangle_size / 2.0
    cx = rectangle_size * i + cy

    # Annotation You can change color,font, etc ..
    ax.annotate(str(nums[i]), (cx, cy), color='black', weight='bold', fontsize=20, ha='center', va='center')

# For squared look
plt.xlim([0, rectangle_size*len(nums)])
plt.ylim([0, rectangle_size])

# We dont want to show ticks
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using the [`Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) patch is:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

x = np.random.randn(5).round(2).tolist()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 2))  # make figure

dx = 0.15  # edge size of box
buf = dx / 10  # buffer around edges

# set x and y limits
ax.set_xlim([0 - buf, len(x) * dx + buf])
ax.set_ylim([0 - buf, dx + buf])

# set axes as equal and turn off axis lines
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.axis("off")

# draw plot
for i in range(len(x)):
    # create rectangle with linewidth=4     
    rect = Rectangle((dx * i, 0), dx, dx, facecolor="none", edgecolor="black", lw=4)
    ax.add_patch(rect)

    # get text position
    x0, y0 = dx * i + dx / 2, dx / 2
     
    # add text
    ax.text(
        x0, y0, f"{x[i]}", color="black", ha="center", va="center", fontsize=28, fontweight="bold"
    )

fig.tight_layout()

fig.show()
```

which gives:

[image]